# Can I edit .obj file in Meshlab or Blender?

Tags: graphics, blender, meshlab

I have .obj file of tree and I want to remove some portion of it. Is it possible to do so in Meshlab?

Comment: You can import it in Blender. About Meshlab, I dont know..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of them support .obj files.

- http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/
- http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ

Comment: Use the Select Vertices (or Faces) tool, then do Filter / Delete Vertices (or Faces). Check these videos out for Meshlab Basics: https://www.youtube.com/user/mrpmeshlabtutorials

Answer (score 0):

No they will not open in Blender! I have a few I'd love to edit, & downloaded blender since it was free, & they will not open in it, no mater what!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you can manually edit .OBJ meshes by selecting edges or faces in Edit Mode, but is there an easier way to do it?

(ie, the Decimate Modifier does not work.  It can take a lot of time reducing polygons on a high poly mesh manually...)

Comment: I guess a better question would be:

Is there a better format to use other than an OBJ file?
(When transferring meshes from AutoCAD/Autodesk to Blender)